# Issues with Bootstrap NavBar Submenu changing position on click

Tags: javascript, html, css, bootstrap-4

I've created a navigation bar with sub menus, using Bootstrap v4.2.1. Hovering OnClick are implemented through Javascript. Problem is whenever I load the page and hover over a submenu item, the menu opens up but appears right below the item. When I click the menu, it disappears and reappears on the right side of the submenu. Ideally, I'd want to have the submenu appear at the right side of the dropdown menu, not appear at the bottom upon initial hover. I'm suspecting that there might be something I might've missed in my Javascript but I could be wrong. Any help/advice would be greatly appreciated. 
Here's my fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/fzev07tb/

```js
//Script to toggle navbar dropdown
$(document).ready(function() {

  $('.navbar .dropdown-item').on('click', function(e) {
    var $el = $(this).children('.dropdown-toggle');
    var $parent = $el.offsetParent(".dropdown-menu");
    $(this).parent("li").toggleClass('open');

    if (!$parent.parent().hasClass('navbar-nav')) {
      if ($parent.hasClass('show')) {
        $parent.removeClass('show');
        $el.next().removeClass('show');
        $el.next().css({
          "top": -999,
          "left": -999
        });
      } else {
        $parent.parent().find('.show').removeClass('show');
        $parent.addClass('show');
        $el.next().addClass('show');
        $el.next().css({
          "top": $el[0].offsetTop,
          "left": $parent.outerWidth() - 4
        });
      }
      e.preventDefault();
      e.stopPropagation();
    }
  });

  $('.navbar .dropdown').on('hidden.bs.dropdown', function() {
    $(this).find('li.dropdown').removeClass('show open');
    $(this).find('ul.dropdown-menu').removeClass('show open');
  });

});

//Script for OnHover OnClick NavBar Item -->
jQuery(function($) {
  if ($(window).width() > 769) {
    $('.navbar .dropdown').hover(function() {
      $(this).find('.dropdown-menu').first().stop(true, true).delay(250).slideDown();

    }, function() {
      $(this).find('.dropdown-menu').first().stop(true, true).delay(100).slideUp();

    });

    $('.navbar .dropdown > a').click(function() {
      location.href = this.href;
    });

  }
});
```

Comment: Can you add the css and html or update fiddle link - it's not working

Comment: Hello GramThanos, I've added the necessary codes in that fiddle link. On my side, the fiddle works. Not quite sure why it's not working for you.

Comment: Yea nah - can you add HTML CSS